# PHP change correct character encoding into unknown character encoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm working on a **PHP** website it has a administrator panel to update content in website ..

when i try to insert content into **MySql** database everything works fine and content show correctly into my website but when i try to edit my content every text changed to unknown character like this

**" Ø§Ø³Ø§Ûï¿½Ûï¿½ ØªØ§Ùï¿½Ûï¿½Ùï¿½ Ú©Ùï¿½Ùï¿½Ø¯Ú¯Ø§Ùï¿ "** ..

My website worked in Persian Language and i use

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
```

Im new at **PHP** and i don't have any idea why this happened ..

here my Edit Page

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php
                   session_start();
                  if($_SESSION['karbar']!=null){}
                  else{
                      header("Location:../login.php");}
                     echo "  <nav class=\"collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse\"> " ;
echo "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">";
                                  echo "<li><a class='exit' style='text-decoration:none' href='logout.php'>خروج</a></li> ";
                                                            echo"    <li style=\"margin-top:14px;\" >   ";
                          echo $_SESSION['karbar']  ;
                          echo " </li>";
                          echo "</ul>";
                         echo " </nav> ";


             ?>
<?php
    /*
        Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
    */

    // connect to the database
    // server info
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'isatisbc_user';
$pass = '**********';
$db = 'isatisbc_db';

// connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

// show errors (remove this line if on a live site)
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

    // creates the new/edit record form
    // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
    function renderForm($Project_Title = '', $Project_Desc ='', $error = '', $id = '')
    { ?>
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>
                                  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="description">
<meta content="" name="keywords">
<meta content="" name="author">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "TextBody",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,"
    +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    height:"350px",
    width:"600px"
});

</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Admin/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/font-awesome.css"> 
                <title>
                    ویرایش
                </title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>

            <header class="navbar  navbar-default" id="top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">نمایش وب سایت</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                <li>
          <a href="news.php">اخبار</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="../components/">مطالب</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="essay.php">مقالات</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="event.php">رویداد ها</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="index.php">خدمات و پروژه ها <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu ">

                            <li><a href="index.php">عناوین</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="active"><a href="ProjectImg.php">تصاویر</a></li>

                        </ul>
                      </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</header>


    <div class="" id="content" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>ویرایش پروژه</h1>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">


      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-11" role="main">
                             <form method="post" action="">  
                                                <?php if ($id != '') { ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                          <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" size="95" value="<?php echo $Project_Title; ?>">  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">عنوان خدمات :</div>
</div>
                                         <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> <textarea id="TextBody" name="TextBody" rows="15" ><?php echo $Project_Desc; ?></textarea>     </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">توضیحات خدمات :</div>
</div>

                                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-info"/>

                             </form>

          </div>



               </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-11" role="main">



          </div>


</div>
               </div>
              </div>
            <div class="footer">
                         </div>
         </div>
        </form>






            <script src="Admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="Admin/js/ie10.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
                    <?php } ?>

    <?php }



        /*

           EDIT RECORD

        */
    // if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
            if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
            {
                // get variables from the URL/form
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $Title = htmlentities($_POST['Title'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $TextBody = htmlentities($_POST['TextBody'], ENT_QUOTES);

                // check that Title and TextBody are both not empty
                if ($Title == '' || $TextBody == '')
                {
                    // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                    renderForm($Title, $TextBody, $error, $id);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table_project SET  Project_Title = ?, Project_Desc = ?
                        WHERE id=?"))
                    {
                        $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $Title, $TextBody, $id);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();
                    }
                    // show an error message if the query has an error
                    else
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                    }

                    // redirect the user once the form is updated

                                     header("Location: index.php");


                }
            }
            // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
            else
            {
                echo "Error!";
            }
        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
        else
        {
            // make sure the 'id' value is valid
            if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
            {
                // get 'id' from URL
                $id = $_GET['id'];

                // get the recod from the database
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_project WHERE id=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $Title, $TextBody);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    // show the form
                    renderForm($Title, $TextBody, NULL, $id);

                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
                }
            }
            // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }
    }

?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

I'm trying to be the coding perfect Web site and, if there is one thing that helped me, thanks y'all tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` and declare your table column `CHARACTER SET utf8`.